# Error: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCPicker" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, libraries

**Overview:**

I built an NPM library using TypeScript and it's been almost 9 months since I've last updated it (I didn't have the time). However, it uses the following libraries:

1. [react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal)
2. [@react-native-picker/picker](https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker) (Used to be [@react-native-community/picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/picker), but that library is **now deprecated in favor of the new library**)
3. [@react-native-community/datetimepicker](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker)

**My Library (react-native-ultimate-modal-picker) `package.json`:**

I have all 3 of the listed libraries above set as `peerDependencies`, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something else like `podfiles`.

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": ">=3.0.0",
  "@react-native-picker/picker": ">=1.8.3",
  "react": "*",
  "react-native": "*",
  "react-native-modal": ">=11.0.0"
},
```

**What Works:**

The code works when running in the iOS Simulator, but when adding the my library [react-native-ultimate-modal-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ultimate-modal-picker) to a project, it gives the error.

**Error:**

```
Error: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCPicker" was not found in the UIManager.
```

**Imported NPM Library into project:**

```js
import { DropdownList } from 'react-native-ultimate-modal-picker';

const testItems: Array<PickerValue> = [
  { label: '1', value: '1' },
];

<DropdownList
  title="Test"
  items={testItems}
  onChange={(value: string) => console.log(value)}
/>
```

**Github Repo (My Library that currently isn't working)**

https://github.com/jefelewis/react-native-ultimate-modal-picker

**Possible Reasons For Issues:**

- `podfiles`?
- Cache?
- Improper build/export of NPM library?

Answer (score 2):

Can try steps below:

1. `rm -rf node_modules && yarn cache clean && yarn install`
2. `cd ios && pod install`
3. Open xCode from yourapp.xcworkspace file inside ios folder.
4. Select `Clean Build Folder` from xCode product menu.
5. `Run` your app directly from xCode product menu.

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly ! i had the same issue

Answer (score 1):

The below solution worked for me.
Install the below-mentioned package apart from react-native-picker-select

// React Native CLI

```
npm install @react-native-community/picker
npx pod-install
```

// Expo users

```
expo install @react-native-community/picker
```

Credit - https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-react-native-picker-select/

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your podfile:

```
pod 'RNCPicker', :path => './ReactComponent/node_modules/@react-native-picker/picker'
```

the path you may need change to your real path like others in your podfile and pod install again.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using [react-native-picker-select](https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select) with RN above 0.60 you also need to install `@react-native-community/picker`
(not sure why it is not a dependency of it...)

```
npm install @react-native-community/picker

pod-install
```

Answer (score 0):

For  to work install both npm packages and pod install
or add these lines in your package.json and pod install

"@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.4",

"react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",

---

like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.4",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing the pod manually seems to have worked. in the podfile, add pod 'RNCPicker', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-picker/picker'

Note: the path could be different depending on the structure of the project. This works if podfile is located inside of ios folder ( using react-native generated projects

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Kindly make sure you have both the below dependencies installed (update versions accordingly).

```
"react-native-picker-select": "^8.1.0",    
"@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.3.1", // needed as a dependency for the above package
```

Please see: https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select#versioning